# Use "and" and "or" logic inside of "Countifs" formula Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I want to have have two formulas, I want to have an effect like below

```
=countifs( A2:A. "<=" & today(), B2:B, or("="&"C1", and("<="&"C2+C1", ">="&"C1-C2")))
```

[image]

but by searching trough online, "countifs" is not working with "and" and "or" logic,
but I couldn't find a replacement which fit on this situation.

Would it be possible to solve without scripting or referring on another cell but only with pure formulas and not refer another cells to check ?
additionally, I want to get a value of C4, which also on same condition if it can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the `=` part and just bracket high and low:

```
=countifs( A2:A, "<=" & today(), B2:B, "<="&C2+C1,B2:B, ">="&C1-C2)
```

Comment: oh yes ! thanks for saving me, I wonder could be be tough to solve the succession though ?

Comment: One post one question.  subsequent question should get their own post.  Currently it is not evident, to me, at least what you mean by `succession`.  Ask a new question that explains better what you want.

Comment: thanks! yeah i'll right on a new question, thanks for quick and smart answer ! have a good day!